# sort an array of object inside that is object inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, indexing

```
var Arryofobject = [{
a= "string",
b = {pos:[1,2,...],kind:[bar,bar1,...],name:[foo,foo1,...],val:[20,30,...]}
}]
```

the above syntax presenting my question, 
the variables are taken from an html input , 
the output is of course without the key ,
1 bar foo 20
2 bar1 foo1 30

i need to run a function that sorts b.val and arrange all object with the bigger value  to be the first position in the output , meaning
2 bar1 foo1 30
1 bar foo 20

- the pos need to be left with the value .
- foo1- could be blabla as well so the 1 attached to foo shpuld not be considered.

i have tried to use the map , but return always blocking me to continue count my index .

Comment: var Arryofobject = [{
a:"string",
b:{pos:[1,2,...],kind:[bar,bar1,...],name:[foo,foo1,...],val:[20,30,...]}
}]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] along with the code that isn't working as expected.

Comment: Give a sample input and expected output.